# TFT-LCD VCOM powered by LDO

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, lcd, display, tft

Is it possible to generate VCOM voltage for TFT-LCD display by LDO? I am considering using MAX16929 for generating AVDD (9.6V), VGL (-6V), VGH (18V) and VDD (3.3V) for touch controller, but remaining voltage I need to generate is VCOM (3.8V). After brief research I have seen that many other chips used for powering display use some buffers for generating this voltage. Are this buffers mandatory or can I make voltage by simple adjustable LDO (converting 5V generated by different buck regulator to 3.8V)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supply the required voltage from wherever or whatever you want. Just be careful about the voltage limits and current demand, although the VCOM current requirement of the LCDs is generally low.

Some of the LCDs I worked with (10" mostly) were happy with 3.3V of VCOM but for your application you should still check the accepted limits from the LCD's datasheet.

I remember that I had used an ICL7660 equivalent as a double output generator (positive and negative doubler) and used Zener-based linear regulators as post regulators to generate the required voltages.